# Python how to convert string to bytes?

Tags: python

i need to conver strings like that "aa28f5c91a24293a3278" to get result in bytes, like that "b'\xaa(\xf5\xc9\x1a$):2x'"
How to do that in python? thanks!

Comment: try `"aa28f5c91a24293a3278".encode()`

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode i know, it looks the same when it gets printed, sry didn't thought about that

Comment: It helps if you can tell us what that string is. There is a good answer assuming that this is a hex encoded string. If that's true, post that info in your question.

Answer (score 2):

With [`bytes.fromhex(my_hex_string)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex):

```
>>> s = "aa28f5c91a24293a3278"
>>> bytes.fromhex(s)
b'\xaa(\xf5\xc9\x1a$):2x'
```

> This bytes class method returns a `bytes` object, decoding the given string object. The string must contain two hexadecimal digits per byte, with ASCII whitespace being ignored.